# Dynamic stored procedure execution

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of stored procedures in a table with date time which need to be executed dynamically / simultaneously.

Normal execution is working fine, but executing all procedures sequentially.

Table structure

```
+----------+----------+-----------------------+
| Screenid | SP Name  |     ExecutionTime     |
+----------+----------+-----------------------+
|   102457 | SPName1  | 2017-03-02 09:15:000  |
|   103587 | SpName7  | 2017-03-02 09:15:000  |
|   104578 | SPName15 | 2017-03-02 10:25:0000 |
+----------+----------+-----------------------+
```

This is my code:

```
DECLARE Tbl_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT DISTINCT Srctable,SrcSP,Truncatereq,executeReq,exectime
    FROM IDB_Define_Source a (nolock)
    WHERE exectime < getdate()
      AND execstatus = 'N'
    ORDER BY exectime

OPEN Tbl_cursor;  

-- Perform the first fetch.  
FETCH NEXT FROM Tbl_cursor INTO @srctable, @srcSp, @trunreq, @exereq, @exetime ;  

-- Check @@FETCH_STATUS to see if there are any more rows to fetch.  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    BEGIN TRY 
        DECLARE @str nvarchar(max)

        SET @str = 'EXEC reportsdb.reportuser.'+ @srcSp

        EXEC sp_executesql @str

        UPDATE T1
        SET execstatus = 'Y'
        FROM IDB_Define_Source T1
        WHERE Srctable = @srctable
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        UPDATE T1
        SET exectime = exectime + datediff(dd, exectime, getdate()) + 1,
            execstatus = 'Y',
            ErrorDtl = ERROR_MESSAGE()
        FROM IDB_Define_Source T1
        WHERE Srctable = @srctable
    END CATCH

    -- This is executed as long as the previous fetch succeeds.  
    FETCH NEXT FROM Tbl_cursor INTO @srctable, @srcSp, @trunreq, @exereq, @exetime;  
END  

CLOSE Tbl_cursor;  
DEALLOCATE Tbl_cursor;
```

Comment: Need to call it from sql directly? from the SP?

Comment: Provide table structure with sample data, and explain where you are getting difficulty.. so that can help us to understand the problem

Comment: Written a SP to execute it based on the scheduled time.

Comment: plz include what you have tried so far, also add more details to understand the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor then try Logic Like

```html
DECLARE @Query text
SET @Query = (Select Col_SP FROM Tablename)

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Query
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can call all in looping. Get the list from table and make a while loop and call it. Simple example like bellow.

```
DECLARE @Total_Count INT,@Counter  INT = 1;
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by SPName) RowNo,SPName 
INTO #TmpTable
FROM #TableName

SET @Total_Count = (Select Max(RowNo) from #TmpTable);

WHILE @Counter <= @Total_Count 
BEGIN
    Declare @EXESPName Varchar(200);
    @EXESPName = (Select SPName FROM TmpTable WHERE RowNo = @Counter)
   Exec @EXESPName
   SET @Counter = @Counter + 1;
END;
```

Comment: Hi.. This code will execute all SP sequentially. I need to execute all SPs simultaneously